# Function executes correctly as a tkinter button command but not in the script

Tags: python, tkinter, self

This is my first question on StackOverflow. So far lurking was enough to solve all my problems.

I'm a python newbie and I don't fully understand the meaning behind 'self' yet.

I defined a function (not a method. It's not inside a class) as

```
def pcal_thresh(self):
    p_th = p_thresh.get()
    print('p_th')
```

I am trying to use it in 2 separate conditions. First as a command for Tkinter

```
p_thresh = tk.Scale(calibration, from_=255, to=1, length=int(y_height*1.2), command=pcal_thresh)
```

Second, inside another function

```
def confirm():
    if not top_distance == 0:
        pcal_thresh()
```

In this exact configuration the function "pcal_thresh()" executes correctly as a Tkinter command, but not inside another function. If I remove 'self' from the declaration, it's the opposite. Works fine when used inside a function, but not as a Tkinter command. What can be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` does not have a default value, so even if you don't *use* it, you still need to provide a value when you call `pcal_thresh`. As a callback, it receives the new scale value when called.

Either provide a dummy argument

```
def confirm():
    if not top_distance == 0:
        pcal_thresh(None)
```

or provide a default value:

```
def pcal_thresh(self=None):
    p_th = p_thresh.get()
    print('p_th')
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. So Tkinter command is a callback that passes the widget value to the function as "self"?

Comment: Right; if I understand this correctly, the argument to `pcal_thresh` should be the value you want for `p_th`. You don't have to refer to the `Scale` object using a global name.